# sort an array of json document

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I'm wondering if it's possible to sort or bring the min value in case of an array of json. I read something about this issue but found nothing.

This is the Input:

```
{
  "intData": [
    {
      "DATE": "2018",
      "NOME": "raf"
    },
    {
      "DATE": "2001",
      "NOME": "fabio"
    },
    {
      "DATE": "2002",
      "NOME": "fabiola"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would:

```
{
  "intData": [
    {
      "DATE": "2001",
      "NOME": "fabio"
    },
    {
      "DATE": "2002",
      "NOME": "fabiola"
    },
    {
      "DATE": "2018",
      "NOME": "raf"
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "DATE": "2001",
  "NOME": "fabio"
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

## Ordered Results

The steps are as follows:

1. Create object with structure: `$.DATE.NOME.@`
2. Sort it
3. Turn it back into an array

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "intData": {
        "*": {
          "@": "@(1,DATE).@(1,NOME)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "intData.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

## First result

The steps are as follows:

1. Create object with structure: `$.DATE.NOME.@`
2. Sort it
3. Turn it back into an array
4. Get first result

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "intData": {
        "*": {
          "@": "@(1,DATE).@(1,NOME)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "@": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```